# Pass parameters to Facebook App Link from Android App

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am sharing content (such as text, image and app link) to Facebook with following code:

**Step 1:**

```
public void setupFacebookShareIntent() {

    ShareDialog shareDialog;

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentDescription(
                    text1+ " " +text2)
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://example/folder"))
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(path1))
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

Also here the app link metadata:

**Step 2:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="sharesample://story/1234">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.mypackage">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ShareSample">
    <meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the code to handle incoming app link in Activity:

**Step 3:**

```
Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());

        if (targetUrl != null) {

            // If you need to access data that you are passing from the meta tag from your website or from opening app you can get them from AppLinkData.
            Bundle applinkData = AppLinks.getAppLinkData(getIntent());
            String id = applinkData.getString("id");

            // You can also get referrer data from AppLinkData
            Bundle referrerAppData = applinkData.getBundle("referer_app_link");

        } else {
            // Not an applink, your existing code goes here.
        }
```

How can I pass data to app link url properly in *step 1*, such as simple string parameters and then get back in *step 3*?

Comment: nobody has an idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has the same "issue", I'll post my solution:

When I share a link to FB from my app I pass the param in url like that:

```
http://my-app.com/xxxx/xxx.php?id=10
```

and then if user clicks the link on FB, then my app starts and I get the parameter as following:

```
 Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
 String s = targetUrl.getQueryParameter("id");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sin. As i was using facebook app linking service, so really wondering how could i pass it argument. But your solution works perfect. (y)

Comment: I am getting the below error in 11.3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460312/error-cannot-find-symbol-applinks-gettargeturlfrominboundintent-in-com-facebook