# error: cannot find symbol AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent in com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:11.3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

While upgrading the facebook SDK from a lowest version(7.1.0) to latest version (11.3.0) got symbol:   method getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(ItemViewActivity,Intent) location: class AppLinks

I have got

```
error: package bolts does not exist import bolts.AppLinks;
```

So I have modified and fixed the import error

```
import bolts.AppLinks; to import com.facebook.bolts.AppLinks;
```

Now I am getting below error

```
error: cannot find symbol
                AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
                        ^
  symbol:   method getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(ItemViewActivity,Intent)
  location: class AppLinks
```

Code:

```
Uri applinktUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
```

Comment: That method does not exist in the new AppLinks object.
Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I'm using bolts framework for applinks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bolts has been removed from within facebook SDK in version 9.0.0 although it's not mentioned in the release notes
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

You could use the dependency directly from it's opensource project
https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

this would be to add
implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
and keep your old import line
import bolts.AppLinks

Having said this, I don't know how and if Applinks is used anymore within Facebook